# Windows 2003 User folder mapping issue

Tags: windows, logon-scripts

We have a windows 2003 standard domain server/client network with about 450 users. Each user has a login script that maps shares, and syncs the time to the server. Each user account also has a user folder mapped - `\\server\users$\username`. Every so often, a user will login, and their user folder is mapped to the user directory (`\\server\users$`) and they see every user folder? I've looked online, and can't seem to find anything on why this happens. Easy way to fix this is disconnect the folder, log off & log back on and it maps right. Does anyone know why this happens???

Answer (score 1):

We occasionally see this behavior happen on our domain.  It occurs rarely and randomly.  Naturally they don't have permissions into anybodies folder except their own but it is more of a confusion issue.

The issue has to do with the user logging in before the network connection has finished establishing.  If it can't grab the username right you get a username of ""  This makes it map the user drive to \server\users\ rather than \server\users\username  Just waiting a few seconds at logon makes this go away.  Certain computers seem more prone to it than others so check out the network drivers.  I'm not sure why it seems to have the trouble getting the username, I would think it would just use the current username rather than relying on the network.  Could be a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

What does the line in your script look like?  Do you use something like '%username%'?

I use:

```
wshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "H:", "\\server\Users$\" & wshNetwork.UserName, True
```

and never really encounter the problems that you're having.  You should also turn on Access-Based Enumeration to 'hide' the folders that users don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The login script is as follows:
Net time /setsntp:server
Net time \server /set /yes
Net Use I: \server\share1 /persistent:yes
Net use p: \server\share2 /persistent:yes
Net Use S: \server\share3 /persistent:yes

The user folder is not defined in the login script, rather in active directory when we setup there user account. There Home folder is set to connect to the H: drive, and everyone is set to: \server\users$\username.

Comment: Are you sure that's not supposed to say "\\server\users$\%username%"?

Comment: when you type"\\server\users$\%username%" it changes "%username%" to there username, which is what I already have

Answer (score 0):

I never used \server\users$\%username% in Active directory, but I could give it a try...like I said we have 450 users, and this happens maybe once a week to 1 or 2 users....sometimes it wont happen for 6 months, and other times it seems to happen every week...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've seen this issue several times before and it tends to be with workstations which boot too quickly for the LAN infrastructure and therefore finishes booting before the network has completely finished establishing.  The problem seems to be particularly bad on networks with spanning tree or PortFast enabled but you can alleviate the issue in some cases by hard-coding the network speed/duplex settings manually on the workstation (which can be done through GPO I believe).  There is also a GPO setting to force the workstation to wait for a network connection to be established before logging in but this causes problems for offline and wireless laptop users I've found.